# Is ごめんなさいませ idiomatic?

Tags: words, keigo

If so, how formal is it? Please compare it with other apologies.

Comment: In [the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ)](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/), there are 0 results for ごめんなさいませ, compared with 1824 results for ごめんなさい.  That doesn't mean no one ever uses it, but it does mean the version without ませ is *much* more common.

Comment: In [the Google Japanese Web N-Gram corpus](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2009T08), the counts are 8253271 for ごめんなさい and only 3896 for ごめんなさいませ, which gives us a 2000-to-1 ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to talk about the phrase 「ごめんなさい**ませ**」 mostly because it is not in wide use (that is unless there actually exists an area that I am unaware of where it is often said).

I have probably heard it 2-3 times in my life, but that means only once every 10 years or so.  I feel like it has (almost) always been an adult woman who I have heard say it.

To me, a native speaker, 「ごめんなさいませ」 does not necessarily sound formal.  In fact, it actually sounds fairly informal but, at the same time, pretty polite.

If you want to apologize politely, you would be better off using:

「[大変失礼]{たいへんしつれい}いたしました。」、「[本当]{ほんとう}に失礼いたしました。」 or　「本当にごめんなさい。」

because those are what we would use most often ourselves.